# display a checkbox after selecting on a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I have created a drop down menu with animals. But what I wanna do now is, after I have selected one of the animals from the drop down, can I 'display' a checkbox button? Like... hide it initially and then after I have select one of the animals and click on it, the checkbox button will be visible?

I can only do on the code for drop down menu...

```
    <li><a href="#" 
    onmouseover="mopen('m1')" 
    onmouseout="mclosetime()">animals</a>
    <div id="m1" 
        onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" 
        onmouseout="mclosetime()">
    <a href="#">Dogs</a>
    <a href="#">Cats</a>
    <a href="#">Cow</a>
    <a href="#">Goats</a>
    <a href="#">Tiger</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jquery like :

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#chkdogs').show();return false;">Dogs</a>
<input id="chkdogs" type="checkbox" name="dogs" value="dog" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: Thanks! It's something like this that I wanna do. =)

Comment: Hey ikhsan, is it possible to put more than one checkbox? Like 3 - 4 of the checkbox? Thanks

Comment: as long as each checkbox has a different id you can do that, but don't forget to execute $('#chkdogs,#chkcats,#chkcow,..').hide() before, in scenario -> user click dogs, but change his mind and click cat, that will make only showing checkbox that users click and hide the rest

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest you do is:

1. Add the checkboxes dynamically when an onclick event occurs.
2. Or hardcode the checkboxes next to each animal then hide them. Then use the onclick  event to reveal them.
3. Lastly use jquery, it's easier